# Strange Ruby 2+ Behavior with "select!"

Tags: ruby, select

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to find documented or explained anywhere so I'm hoping someone here can help me out. I've verified the unexpected behavior on three versions of Ruby, all 2.1+, *and* verified that it doesn't happen on an earlier version (though it's through tryruby.org and I don't know which version they're using). Anyway, for the question I'll just post some code with results and hopefully someone can help me debug it.

```
arr = %w( r a c e c a r )             #=> ["r","a","c","e","c","a","r"]
arr.select { |c| arr.count(c).odd? }  #=> ["e"]
arr.select! { |c| arr.count(c).odd? } #=> ["e","r"] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ??????
```

I think the confusing part for me is clearly marked and if anyone can explain if this is a bug or if there's some logic to it, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Checking stuff on the same object that is being mutated(`Array#select!` is a mutator) always leads to strange behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're modifying the array *while* you're read from it *while* you iterate over it. I'm not sure the result is defined behavior.  The algorithm isn't required to keep the object in any kind of sane state while it's running.

Some debug printing during the iteration shows why your particular result happens:

```
irb(main):005:0> x
=> ["r", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r"]
irb(main):006:0> x.select! { |c| p x; x.count(c).odd? }
["r", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r"]
["r", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r"]
["r", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r"]
["r", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r"] # "e" is kept...
["e", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r"] # ... and moved to the start of the array
["e", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r"]
["e", "a", "c", "e", "c", "a", "r"] # now "r" is kept
=> ["e", "r"]
```

You can see by the final iteration, there *is* only one `r`, and that the `e` has been moved to the front of the array. Presumably the algorithm modifies the array in-place, moving matched elements to the front, *overwriting* elements that have already failed your test. It keeps track of how many elements are matched and moved, and then truncates the array down to that many elements.

So, instead, use `select`.

---

A longer example that matches more elements makes the problem a little clearer:

```
irb(main):001:0> nums = (1..10).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
irb(main):002:0> nums.select! { |i| p nums; i.even? }
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

You can see that it does indeed move matched elements to the front of the array, overwriting non-matched elements, and then truncate the array.

Comment: excellent answer +1 I was just writing a similar thing in conjunction with your comment above.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to 'p' the array at each step and figure this out myself, but that makes complete sense, though I don't know if it's what the Ruby devs intended. I ran your code on tryruby.org, and at every step, 'x' is just the original array with nothing replaced. I can only speculate that the in-place modification of the newer versions of Ruby was implemented for speed, but I feel like the old behavior is more expected and should have been preserved. Anyway, thank you for thinking to inspect the array at each step and identify the problem for me!

Comment: I personally prefer the old behavior so I'm overriding the bang method to use it, though the new behavior makes sense from a space-complexity standpoint. It feels like an anti-pattern (with respect to Ruby, anyway) to have to write "arr = arr.select etc".

Comment: @user2214364 what do you mean the **"old behavior"** `Array#select!` was introduces in 1.9.3 and although the MRI code has changed a bit the functionality is exactly the same. Not sure why it works differently on tryruby.org but many things are tied down to avoid misuse. If I run your code in 1.9.3p392 using `#select!` I still get `["e","r"]`. Also patching `select!` seems like a bad idea if you want the functionality of `#select` then store the result in a variable.

Comment: @user2214364 I'd strongly, **strongly** recommend against doing that. I would go so far as to say you *must* not do that. Don't override built-in methods, and **especially** don't do it to arbitrarily change their side-effects, just because you don't like them. Program using the language as it's provided to you so that your code is *actually Ruby* and matches everybody's expectations and the documentation, and not some sub-language that only you understand.

Comment: I agree with @meagar. Don't change the core language just to fit your idea of how it should work. Those sort of changes would cause a major uproar in a code-review in my world as we all have to have a common understanding of how the language's basic building blocks behave. Change those assumptions, and compatibility and maintainability go out the window and debugging becomes "unpossible".

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some other ways of accomplishing what you're doing:

```
arr = %w( r a c e c a r )
arr.group_by{ |c| arr.count(c).odd? }        
# => {false=>["r", "a", "c", "c", "a", "r"], true=>["e"]}
arr.group_by{ |c| arr.count(c).odd? }.values 
# => [["r", "a", "c", "c", "a", "r"], ["e"]]
arr.partition{ |c| arr.count(c).odd? }       
# => [["e"], ["r", "a", "c", "c", "a", "r"]]
```

And if you want more readable keys:

```
arr.group_by{ |c| arr.count(c).odd? ? :odd : :even } 
# => {:even=>["r", "a", "c", "c", "a", "r"], :odd=>["e"]}
```

[`partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) and [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) are basic building blocks for separating elements in an array into some sort of grouping, so it is good to be familiar with them.